# How to get the fingure / touch point in winrt Pinch / Zoom Gesture

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using `GestureRecognizer` for manipulating touch events in WinRT And also I am added the following touch settings to the `GestureRecognizer`

```
GestureListener.GestureSettings = GestureSettings.ManipulationScale |
                                          GestureSettings.ManipulationScaleInertia;
```

So my doubt is how I can get the latest two touch points (Finger positions) from these events. I am not trying to pinch and zoom an image. I need to get this pinch / zoom finger position through these events. From where I can find these finger positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PointerPressed Event.

```
private void UIElement_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.GetCurrentPoint(UIElement);   //UIElement - the control on which touch will be made
}
```

The event will be fired as many touches are made.
Each time the event fires, the point could be stored and so that the first two points can be retrieved.

Comment: I am using GestureRecognizer not PointerPressed... Looking for a workqround for that